# How to redirect ssh->capture2 output to STDOUT without buffering?

Tags: perl, ssh, openssh

I am using Net::OpenSSH module. The capture2 function returns the output to a variable which I can print to get the output but I want to do this directly to STDOUT without buffering.

Comment: Half a solution: `$ssh->capture2('find /tmp', { stdout_fh => *STDOUT });` should work, but doesn't. Subclass Net::OpenSSH and remove the offending check.

Comment: Use `system` instead of `capture2`.